# Peculiar Error triggered when calling ERC, org2blog from Windows, OS X

Tags: erc

When I launch ERC or org2blog I get the following error:

> dbus-call-method: peculiar error: "Emacs not compiled with dbus
>   support"

I've been trying to run down this error for weeks. How do I find out where dbus is called from? And how can I make it a non-blocking error?

Let me know if you need more information, other than this is happening on 24.4+.

Comment: Are you running Emacs from Cygwin? If you have Emacs sources, the function that gives this error is, the `dbus-call-method` located in `dbus.el`. If you instrument it for debugging by pressing `C-u C-c C-f` then before this error happens you will enter the debugging mode, which also shows the call stack. By examining the call stack you can find out what function calls this one in order to produce this error. Hopefully after you find that, the code causing it may be configured to avoid that execution path.

Comment: Not running Cygwin on Win32. Native 64-bit build from source a well as the http://sourceforge.net/projects/emacsbinw64/prebuilt binary. On OS X, installed via macports.

I'll give your debugging method a try.

Comment: The suggestion to press `C-u C-c C-f` didn't work. I did some digging in the ERC elisp files. It looks like erc-desktop-notifications.el requires dbus. Even though I'm not using notifications and I don't have it configured explicitly or via customize, I wonder if that is the culprit - i.e. another package that requires erc-desktop-notifications.el.

Turns out that wasn't the culprit. I ran `runemacs -Q`, `M-x load-library RET erc-desktop-notifications`, `M-x erc`, and took the defaults to log into freenode. No peculiar error.

Ideas for next steps?

Comment: `C-u C-c C-f` is what I have for instrumenting a function, but I'm not sure it's an Emacs default kebinding or something I added. So, what I mean was to recomplie that particular function while instrumenting it fro debugging.  You should be able to do that with `C-u M-x edebug-eval-defun`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution thanks to [Punchagan](https://github.com/punchagan). It's listed [here](https://github.com/punchagan/org2blog/issues/189), but I'll add the information here as well.

The problem was in my auth-source configuration. I removed three authentication facilities and the peculiar error went away.

```
(use-package auth-source
  :config
  (setq
   auth-sources '(
                  ;; default
                  ;; "secrets:session"
                  ;; "secrets:Login"
                  "~/.authinfo.gpg"
                  "~/.authinfo"
                  "~/.netrc"
                  )
   epa-file-cache-passphrase-for-symmetric-encryption t
   auth-source-debug 'trivia
   ))
```